# I can't install NetAct

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I can´t install NetAct in R, I use got errors

I used this command:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("lusystemsbio/NetAct", dependencies=T, build_vignettes = T)
```

And got this:

```
library(devtools)
Loading required package: usethis
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘devtools’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘htmltools’ 0.5.2 is already loaded, but >= 0.5.4 is required
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘usethis’ was built under R version 4.1.3 
> install_github("lusystemsbio/NetAct", dependencies=T, build_vignettes = T)
Error in install_github("lusystemsbio/NetAct", dependencies = T, build_vignettes = T) : 
  could not find function "install_github"
```

Someone could help me? please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: could not find function install\_github for R version 2.15.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215710/error-could-not-find-function-install-github-for-r-version-2-15-2)

Comment: NOT a duplicate of the nominated SO Q&A. Read the error messages. The first one tells you that you have an out-of-date version of htmltools (needed for devtools), so ...  update it. That was what prevented `library(devtools)` from succeeding and therefore the second line was not able to be executed. You probably should make sure that devtools is the current version. Then restart R and try that code again. (The probably is another SO Q&A that is a duplicate since there seems to be an aversion to reading error messages.